# Solr Spellcheck case sensitive issue

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene, spell-checking

I would like to implement a "*Did you mean?*" function with Solr. I know that is need using the **spellcheck** component and I applied some configuration for this, but it seems that this doesn't work fine.

The configuration into `solrconfig.xml` is the follows:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <bool name="spellcheck">true</bool>
       <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">en</str>
       <bool name="spellcheck.collate">true</bool>
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">10</int>
       <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
       <bool name="preferLocalShards">false</bool>
     </lst>
     <arr name="last-components">
       <str>spellcheck</str>
     </arr>
</requestHandler>

<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
        <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_spell</str>
        <lst name="spellchecker">
            <str name="name">default</str>          
            <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
            <str name="field">spellcheck_en</str>
        </lst>
        <lst name="spellchecker">
            <str name="name">en</str>
            <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
            <str name="field">spellcheck_en</str>
        </lst>
    ...
</searchComponent>
```

Whereas in `schema.xml` file I have:

```
...
<fieldType name="text_spell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_spell_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(['’])" replacement=" " />
                <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.ManagedSynonymGraphFilterFactory" managed="en" />
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" />
                <filter class="solr.ManagedStopFilterFactory" managed="en" />
                <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="spellcheck_en" type="text_spell_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
...
```

In `spellcheck_en` I have a value indexed as "*Hello*" and I run a query and the following points occur (using `spellcheck.q` parameter):

1. That `<str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_spell</str>`, 
   that as far as I understand it should analyze the incoming query with the fieldType `text_spell`, defined above, seems that it is not applied.
2. The query is case sensitive. That's, if I search for "*hallo*", no correction is returned, instead if I use "*Hallo*" it returns "*Hello*".

In particular I would like to get that if I search for "*hallo*" or "*Hallo*", I will be corrected in the same way with "*Hello*", regardless from the case of the query terms.

What can I do to get this? If you can get me to solve this problem you would be a great help. :) Thanks.

Comment: Your `text_spell_en` type has no lowercasing, so there isn't any lowercased tokens in the index. Try to fix that first, at least.

Comment: If I set it with the lowercase filter, will I return the spelling check in lower case?
I do not want this. I want that spell checking to be in right case. It must return me *Hello* and not *hello*.

Comment: Is there not a solution for this issue? Please.

Comment: I did a test and maybe the issue is not the case, but the number of wrong letters. If I index "HelloWorld" and search for "Halloworld" (there are two wrong letters), it correcting me, but if I search for "halloword" (there are three wrong letters) it no. Thus, the issue seems to be the max number of possible wrong letters to receive a correction. Is there a way to increase this number?

Comment: Solr [only supports 1 or 2 as the distance metric](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/spell-checking.html#directsolrspellchecker) for the default Levenshtein distance with the Direct spell checker, so no, not without recompiling Solr (and the reason is that when the number increases, you'll get less useful suggestions, since a distance of 3 will consume a lot more resources and give far more irrelevant suggestions).

Comment: Beyond this distanceMeasure, is there another distanceMeasure that allow me to enter value larger than 2?